# Nginx subdomain not routing to Node.js

Tags: nginx, subdomain, node.js

I have a subdomain that I want to proxy through Nginx to Node.js.

`domain.tld` is currently routed the standard way through `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`.

However, I also want `subdomain.domain.tld` to route to `domain.tld:8000`.

To do this, I put the following in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/subdomain.domain.tld.conf`:

```
http{
    server {
            listen 0.0.0.0:80;
            server_name subdomain.tld.com;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/subdomain.domain.log;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            }
    }
}
```

Nginx seems to start up fine. The subdomain's nameservers are configured correctly.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a ton for any help in advance.

#### Edit: Also, I symlinked the file from `sites-available/` to `sites-enabled/`.

#### Edit: The exact contents of  `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`:

http://pastebin.com/wZJFPx7H

#### Edit: The error message starting nginx:

```
 Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) 
 nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) 
 nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) 
 nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) 
 nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) 
 nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

Comment: cross post of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903209/run-node-js-on-linode-subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, check for any errors in the log during startup.

It may not be loading this server because of this:

```
proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
```

Which should be changed to:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
```

Beyond that, compare the `listen` directive to that in your other `server` blocks - make sure it matches.  If they're bound to a specific address instead of 0.0.0.0, then this `server` wouldn't be getting the requests.

**edit**:

For those who find this question in the future, the subdomain's `server` block was not being included - and the `include` block must be within the existing `http` block to avoid address binding conflicts.

Comment: I added the `http://` to `subdomain.domain.tld.conf`. In `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`, the normal server for `domain.tld` listens on just "80", would that cause it to not send the request? I need the normal server to listen on port 80 too though, since it needs to serve `domain.tld`.

Comment: Also, I checked both the nginx error and access logs, found nothing. It seems the issue is that the subdomain is getting served to `nginx.conf` instead of my specific subdomain conf file.

Comment: @Archio That ought to work fine, as `listen 0.0.0.0:80` is functionally equivilent to `listen 80`, at least as far as IPv4 is concerned, but go ahead and change them to match - can't hurt.  Can you verify that there's an `include` in the main config pointing to the `sites-enabled` directory?

Comment: Good call, it wasn't... but now that I included it, it's warning me that 0.0.0.0:80 is already in use. In other words, it's not letting me bind `subdomain.domain.tld` to 80 because `domain.tld` is already using it, I think.

Comment: @Archio Did you change the `listen` directives to match?

Comment: Yes, both `listen` directives listen on 0.0.0.0:80;.

Comment: @Archio That should be no problem, then.. nginx most definitely supports `Host:` headers.  Does the warning state that the server block is being ignored?  Or is there perhaps another instance of nginx running taking up the port?

Comment: I know, that's why I'm so confused.... No, the warning state is preventing the server from being running, and I know there isn't another instance taking up the port because it ran fine without the subdomain conf file.

Comment: Strange.. as a sanity check, maybe just check `lsof -i -P | grep 80` while nginx is stopped?

Comment: `lsof -i -P | grep 80` returns nothing, so it has to be coming from the initial nginx instance.

Comment: How on earth.. hrm.  What's the exact error message when it fails to start because of the port conflict?

Comment: I've updated the question with the exact contents of both conf files, as well as the exact error message.

Comment: Oh!  Try moving your `include` within the `http` block.

Comment: IT WORKED! I could kiss you right now! Seriously, thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: @Archio Great, glad to help!